Interpretation of output for Portfolio optimization program
I am new to quantum computing, though I am by now familiar with certain jargon but have miles to go before I gain a foothold on the subject. I have been trying very hard to understand and interpret the output for portfolio optimization of VQE.
To begin with, I am comfortable executing program of Qiskit. I specifically require help with interpreting the output of VQE and QAOA in the following program (Qiskit PO)
Optimal: selection [1. 0. 0. 1.], value -0.0149

I believe the first column is the asset combination that should be present in the portfolio, the decimal values that we see in the middle column are the energy values, and we are looking at the lowest energy level as the answer. I am not able to understand the third column. Could someone help?

VQE and QAOA, or any other variational method, are in principle heuristics. It means that finding an optimal solution is not guaranteed and sometimes the result can be very far from the optimum. However, given enough repeated runs of the algorithm, we can find the optimum or a solution very close to it.
This is also case of your portfolio optimization. The algorithm run several times, and as you can see from the results, it found several possible combinations of assets. However, probabilities of finding such solutions differ. So, the third column in the results table is a probability that a particular solution is found if the algorithm is run. As you can also see, the probability is the highest for actual optimum but this is not a rule, especially in case of large number of assets.
Also, have a look at the linked documentation. Here you can see that probability of finding the optimum is 1 for an exact solver, i.e. the algorithm able to find solution always. This nicely illustrates a difference between heuristics and exact solvers.
Concerning the first column, it is really combination of assets. If a vector member is one then respective asset is included to the portfolio, if it is zero then the asset is not included.
The second column should be value of an objective function which is combination of portfolio return and risk (including risk aversion hyperparameter).
It is true that the objective function value is linked to energy of a quantum system underlying the optimization (in particular spin glasses described by so-called Ising Hamiltonian).
